# Display custom post type taxonomies as an archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, archives

Hello I have a custom post type called `results`. I also created categories for that specific post type using a taxonomy. I'm not sure if I set it up correctly, but the code I have works so I'm sticking with it. If you see a better way or any errors please let me know.

I am able to create a custom post and set a category to it. Next I would like to create a categories page that will act like the regular archive.php but just for the category of the custom post types.

So say I have a custom post for `results` and I have its category set to `car accidents` I would like a way to display them all just like archive.php does for normal posts.

I tried going to a url like this but I get sent to a 404 page, even though I have an archive-results.php

`www.myurl.com/results/categories/car-accidents`

Here is the code I used to set up the custom post type and the taxonomy. Sorry If its long but I feel like its necessary to include everything.

```
// Create custom post type
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'Results',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Results' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Results' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'results'),
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'results', 'result-category' ),
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );

//Create category for specific post type
function tr_create_my_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'results-categories',
        'results',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Result Categories' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'result-category' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy' );
```

Am I missing something that is preventing this url from working?

`www.myurl.com/results/categories/car-accidents`

Thanks in advance

Comment: you set it to `result-category` where you registered the taxonomy, change that to `results/categories`

Comment: in the first or second functin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your desired URLs:

```
www.example.com/results/post-name/
www.example.com/results/categories/category-name/
```

Two changes from your original code:

1. Priority was added to both `add_action` hooks to reverse the order they execute. Order matters in this case, because the post type's attachment rewrite rules override the taxonomy rewrites. Side-effect: attachment URLs don't work for this post type!
2. Rewrite for the taxonomy was changed to `results/categories`.

---

```
// Create custom post type
function create_posttype() {
    register_post_type( 'results',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Results' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Results' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'results'),
            'taxonomies'  => array( 'results', 'result-category' ),
        )
    );
}
// ADDED PRIORITY
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype', 9 );

//Create category for specific post type
function tr_create_my_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'results-categories',
        'results',
        array(
            'label' => __( 'Result Categories' ),
            // CHANGED SLUG
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'results/categories' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}
// ADDED PRIORITY
add_action( 'init', 'tr_create_my_taxonomy', 8 );
```

Also note that the most specific general template for this will be `taxonomy-results-categories.php`, which will fall back to `taxonomy.php`, then `archive.php`.