# How to rewrite custom taxonomy term archive to use THE SAME SLUG/front as CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, archives

What I have:

```
example.com/movies/{post} <!-- custom Post Type single post, e.g. /movies/batman -->

example.com/genres/{term} <!-- custom Taxonomy single term e.g. /genres/action -->
```

What I want:

```
example.com/movies/action <!-- custom taxonomy **archive** showing "movie" posts tagged with "action" taxonomy term -->
```

**Is this possible?** I have seen lots of questions with very vague answers but I cannot parse the `add_rewrite_rule` documentation to figure out whether this is something that can be done.

NOTE: I only have a handful of terms in total, so I could hard-code individual rewrites for each if that is an option — I just cannot figure out how!

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/55462/taxonomy-archive-with-same-slug-as-custom-post-type) is more or less a duplicate, but the only non-zero-voted answer is essentially "you can hardcode it but I recommend that you just not do it instead", so I'm hoping someone can actually answer the question of how that would be done…)

Comment: Would a url like this be acceptable? www.example.com/movies/genres/action/? If so, this may have an answer for you here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/275825/display-custom-post-type-taxonomies-as-an-archive-page